# Can Pakistani holding Italian resident along with refugee travel document enter Bulgaria without visa

Tags: visa-free-entry, pakistani-citizens, refugees, bulgaria, italian-residents

I am Pakistani national holding Italian resident along with refugee travel document . Kindly let me know that I can enter Bulgaria without visa .

Comment: What did the Bulgarian embassy tell you when you asked them?

Comment: Welcome to TravelSE. Which Convention document do you hold https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b?